# nifi - fetchsftp - subfolders

Tags: ftp, expression, sftp, apache-nifi

I am using nifi to transfer files between ftp locations.

I have to transfer files from a sftp location to a ftp directory.

I have the below folder structure in the remote sftp location.

- /rootfolder/

  - /subfolder1
  - /subfolder2
  - /subfolder3

I need to download respective files from each subfolder to a local directory which has the similar structure.

My workflow includes

```
ListSFTP -> FetchSFTP (3) -> PutFTP
```

In ListSFTP
Remote path: /rootfolder

In FetchSFTP1
Remote path: /rootfolder/subfolder1

In FetchSFTP2
Remote path: /rootfolder/subfolder2

In FetchSFTP3
Remote path: /rootfolder/subfolder3

But, this does not seem to work. can someone help me how i can transfer files from a remote sftp sub-folder(s).

Thanks,

Aadil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set ListSFTP to recursive search and then coming out of ListSFTP each flow file will have attributes for "path" ad "filename".

Lets say you had one file under each directory in your example, you should get three flow files like the following:

ff 1
path = /rootfolder/subfolder1
filename = file1

ff 2
path = /rootfolder/subfolder2
filename = file2

ff 3
path = /rootfolder/subfolder3
filename = file3

You should only need one FetchSFTP processor with Remote Filename set to ${path}/${filename}.

If you have the same structure on your destination system, just set PutFTP's Remote Path to ${path}.

If you have a slightly different structure, use UpdateAttribute to modify "path" right before PutFTP.